# Редактирование шаблона в админке (YII2)

Tags: css, yii2, bootstrap

Где можно отредактировать вид таблицы в админке? 
В исходнике страницы указывается такой путь:

```
/assets/969eecfc/css/bootstrap.css
```

Нахожу только что-то похожее по такому пути

```
web->assets->969eecfc->css->bootstrap.css
```

Но когда редактирую что-то - нет никаких изменений. Удаляю всё в файле, чищу куки - нет никакого эффекта. Где найти нужный *.css* файл?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь править и удалять временные файлы yii2. Это не приводит ни к какому результату, т.к. эти файлы заново грузятся из сети под новыми именами в случае изменения и удаления. Нужно создать свой css файл и править все в нем.

Comment: Как правильно это сделать? Создать копию bootstrap.css в своей папке view/admin/css ? Но как тогда подключить этот файл вместо текущего?

Comment: Посоветую только прочитать всю документацию(особенно [про ресурсы](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-assets/)), не пропуская ничего. Т.к. у вас полное непонимание того, как все устроено. Помочь вам будет сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какой у вас шаблон. Если Basic, то вносите изменения в web/css/site.css, если Advanced, то backend/web/css/site.css.
Также в зависимости от степени замороченности могут быть доп. файлы css, которые могут быть прописаны напрямую во view

1. Напрямую во view
2. В Layout (views/layout в basic-шаблоне)
3. Подключены через [Asset](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) (наиболее правильный способ)

Comment: Шаблон Basic. Вносил изменения в web/css/site.css - нет никакого эффекта. Папки backend - нет (значит не Advanced). Во view-> layout-> admin.php прописано:

Comment: <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->endBody() ?></body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>